# EXCEL: MAX IF with multiple criteria to return name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, max, pivot-table, rank

I have the following task: Which country had has the highest level of traffic in week 11? 
This is a snapshot of the table (with over 60.000 lines):
[image]

There is week 11 and 12 and multiple countries, so I need to find the country in week 11 which returns the highest sessions number/measure. I tried MAXIF and VLOOKUP, but I can't find a way to either return a name or incorporate multiple criteria (here: week 11 as restriction). 
Any suggestions what to do?

Comment: Can you go per country and use `Countifs`? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842

Answer (score 1):

Your data is *begging* to be used in a **Pivot Table**.

1. Highlight all of your data
2. Click *Insert*, then *Pivot Table*, then *OK*
3. Drag "Sessions" into your Values field and "Country" into your Rows field

By default the pivot table will give you a sum of sessions per country, you want to change this to a max

4. In the Values field, click on "Sum of traffic" then *Value field settings*
5. Summarize your data by max

[image]

And there you go!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got it in 2 steps.  Still trying to join them together into 1 formula.

Assuming that you enter your chosen week "2016-11" in H1

Enter the following formula in I1 to get the max number for that week

```
=MAX(IF(B2:B60000=$H$1,D2:D60000))
```

Enter this formula in J1 to get the country that matches the week and the max number.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$D$60000,SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$60000=$H$1)*($D$2:$D$60000=$I$1),ROW($D$2:$D$60000)-1),ROW(1:1)),1),"")
```

IMPORTNANT use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> when inputing these formulas.

**UPDATE**

SINGLE FORMULA assuming you have the week "2016-##" in H1

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$D$60000,SMALL(IF(($B$2:$B$60000=$H$1)*($D$2:$D$60000=MAX(IF(B2:B60000=$H$1,D2:D60000))),ROW($D$2:$D$60000)-1),ROW(1:1)),1),"")
```